# Validating multiple file inputs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have a problem with validating mutiple file inputs. Whenever i submit, only the first / first used field is validated.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
...
<tr>
<td>Photo1:</td>
<td> <input type="file" class="ipfile" name="pic[]" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Photo2:</td>
<td> <input type="file" class="ipfile" name="pic[]" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Photo3:</td>
<td> <input type="file" class="ipfile" name="pic[]" /> </td>
</tr>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#fnpMain").validate(
    {
    rules:{
        Telefon:{required:true, exactlength:9, digits:true}
    }}
    );

    $("input.ipfile").each(function(){
       $(this).rules("add", {
           required:true,
           accept: "jpg|jpeg"
       });                   
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is what you are expecting.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/7nSey/2/)**

I have used this **[jquery-plugin-validation](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js)** file from this **[bassistance.de](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)** site.

### HTML:

```
<form id="fnpMain">
    <table>
        <tr> 
            <td>Photo1:</td> 
            <td> 
                <input type="file" class="ipfile" name="pic0" /> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Photo2:</td> 
            <td> 
                <input type="file" class="ipfile" name="pic1" /> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Photo3:</td> 
            <td> 
                <input type="file" class="ipfile" name="pic2" /> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </table>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

### JS:

```
$("#fnpMain").validate();

$("input.ipfile").each(function(){        
    $(this).rules("add", {            
        required:true,            
        accept: "jpg|jpeg"        
    });                        
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i want, BUT unfortunately, name attributes have to be "pic[]". It is an array for later php use.